# RedisCache StackExchange client - IDatabase.KeyDeleteAsync - Need scenarios when it returns false

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

We are using Stackexchange client to connect to Redis.
Redis has method, IDatabase.KeyDeleteAsync and it returns boolean value. In which scenarios this method will return false?

Answer (score 3):

It will return false when the key does not previously exists (when the [DEL](http://redis.io/commands/del) command returns 0).

For example:

```
var ctx = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379");
var db = ctx.GetDatabase();

db.StringSet("key", "value");
var @true = db.KeyDelete("key");
var @false = db.KeyDelete("key");
```

You can check the source code of [DemandZeroOrOneProcessor](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/ResultProcessor.cs#L322) where is the logic to set the result to *true* when the command returns 1, and *false* when the command returns 0.

Comment: Thanks.
Any other scenario when it returns false?

Comment: According to https://redis.io/commands/del the Redis command itself returns 0 if the key does not exists which the library code converts to false https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/src/StackExchange.Redis/ResultProcessor.cs#L400

Comment: I've checked locally and it seems that you will get always false as  result if fire and forget is used.
`await db.KeyDeleteAsync(key, CommandFlags.FireAndForget)`